# Extreme slow query for a simple indexed selection - Why?

Tags: postgresql, index, configuration, json, explain

i have a table in my database that is described as follows:

```
-- Table: public.devicemeasurement_mqtt

-- DROP TABLE public.devicemeasurement_mqtt;

CREATE TABLE public.devicemeasurement_mqtt
(
    measurement_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('devicemeasurement_mqtt_measurement_id_seq'::regclass),
    insert_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    data jsonb NOT NULL,
    smart_device_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT devicemeasur_smart_device_id_ee500e1e_fk_d FOREIGN KEY (smart_device_id)
        REFERENCES public.device_mqtt (device_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.devicemeasurement_mqtt
    OWNER to postgres;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.devicemeasurement_mqtt TO postgres;

-- Index: dev_insert__2df020_idx

-- DROP INDEX public.dev_insert__2df020_idx;

CREATE INDEX dev_insert__2df020_idx
    ON public.devicemeasurement_mqtt USING btree
    (insert_time DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;


-- Index: devicemeasurement_mqtt_smart_device_id_ee500e1e

-- DROP INDEX public.devicemeasurement_mqtt_smart_device_id_ee500e1e;

CREATE INDEX devicemeasurement_mqtt_smart_device_id_ee500e1e
    ON public.devicemeasurement_mqtt USING btree
    (smart_device_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

This table, is continuously used from a service that inserts tons of data every minute (at this time it contains around 3 milions of rows), now, in the current situation, when i have to select one device that has continuous measurements the problem does not exist, but, suppose that i have to select the measurements for a specific device that was in use three months ago and now it's disabled (so, no more new measurements), the execution of a simple and effective query like below is really slow, taking up 40 seconds to complete:

This is the reference query that generates this slow select:

```
EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE) 
SELECT 
  devicemeasurement_mqtt.measurement_id, 
  devicemeasurement_mqtt.insert_time,
  devicemeasurement_mqtt.data,
  devicemeasurement_mqtt.smart_device_id
FROM 
  devicemeasurement_mqtt 
WHERE 
  devicemeasurement_mqtt.smart_device_id = 4 
ORDER BY 
  devicemeasurement_mqtt.insert_time DESC
LIMIT 15
```

and here you can find: [the explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/nU0O) and the [database configuration](https://pastebin.com/1q240ZLg)

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..40.04 rows=15 width=264) (actual time=39133.474..39134.059 rows=15 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=22093 read=112101
  ->  Index Scan using dev_insert__2df020_idx on devicemeasurement_mqtt  (cost=0.43..356203.28 rows=134878 width=264) (actual time=39133.471..39134.055 rows=15 loops=1)
        Filter: (smart_device_id = 4)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1794148
        Buffers: shared hit=22093 read=112101
Planning Time: 0.133 ms
Execution Time: 39134.085 ms
```

I'll be glad if someone will help me to figure out!

Comment: How many records are there for `smart_device_id = 4` ? I'm guessing quite a few. If you often want to find the most recent entries for a device, you should probably drop that index and create one on the combination `smart_device_id, insert_time desc`.

Comment: Thanks @Colin'tHart, i've created an index as you described, executed vacuum, analyze and reindex, this is in terms of performance here you can see the execution plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/zby0 - i see that is not using the new created index!